# Process.Start takes long time to start outside application

Tags: c#

I have a method that launches a second exe. The issue I'm having is that if I'm in debug mode in Visual Studio and I put a breakpoint directly after the Process.Start call my second application launches immediately but if I have no break points in VS or run my main C# application outside of VS the launching of my second application via Process.Start can take up to two minutes. My method is below and where I put my breakpoint to see an immediate launch of the 2nd app is at line "if(null != _ProcessMine)". I put the launch of the second exe in a worker thread because when I close my main exe I want the second exe to close also.

```
    public static void RunBtnProcessThread(string processName, String sArgs, Button btn)
    {
        // disable the button until we release the newly launched process
        btn.Enabled = false;

        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        worker.DoWork += (doWorkSender, doWorkArgs) =>
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = processName;
            startInfo.Arguments = sArgs;
            try
            {   
                using ( _ProcessMine = Process.Start(startInfo))
                {
                    if(null != _ProcessMine)
                        _ProcessMine.WaitForExit();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string _Funk = ReflectionHelper.GetMethodFullName(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());

                // error
                Debug.Assert(false, "Error: " + ex.Message);

                // Log error.
                TraceUtil.LogException(_Funk, ex);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        };

        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (completedSender, completedArgs) =>
        {
            btn.Enabled = true;

            _ProcessMine)= null;
        };            

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a separate thread for your scenario.  You can accomplish the same thing by subscribing to the `Process.Exited()` event:

```
    public static void RunBtnProcessThread(string processName, String sArgs, Button btn)
    {
        // disable the button until we release the newly launched process
        btn.Enabled = false;

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = processName;
        startInfo.Arguments = sArgs;

        try
        {
            _ProcessMine = Process.Start(startInfo);
            _ProcessMine.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            _ProcessMine.Exited += (sender, e) =>
            {
                btn.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { 
                    btn.Enabled = true; 
                });
                _ProcessMine = null;
            };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string _Funk = ReflectionHelper.GetMethodFullName(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());

            // error
            Debug.Assert(false, "Error: " + ex.Message);

            // Log error.
            TraceUtil.LogException(_Funk, ex);
        }
    }
```

You could close it using something like:

```
    void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_ProcessMine != null && !_ProcessMine.HasExited)
        {
            // Depending on the type of app:
            _ProcessMine.CloseMainWindow();
            // ... or ...
            _ProcessMine.Kill(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Idle_mind, tried it your way same result. Yes it will launch and close the second app when the first app closes but again, it hangs if I let it run without break points. Put a break point at "_ProcessMine.EnableRaisingEvents = true;" and it opens instantly. It almost like I need some kind of timer/idle there. I tried Thread.Sleep but that didn't work either. Thanks for looking at it.